# Custom selector with background color and imageview in android

Tags: android, layout, background, imageview, selector

I am implementing a `ListView` `MultiModeListener` and therefore creating a selector element to highlight the chosen item(s) in the list.

My selector looks something like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_activated="true"
    android:drawable="@color/Thistle" />
</selector>
```

[image]

However, the ideal state that I desired is shown in the image above. Like the chooser in Whatsapp. From what I can undestand, there's a semi transparent "foreground" image with an icon/image of a check symbol on top of it. I want to know how can I create such a custom selector that sets my background image and an icon on top of every selected item.

I am using the `Selector` as a foreground element in my Framelayout like so:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:padding="6dip"
android:foreground="@drawable/statelist_item_background">
....
```

So can I have a custom selector on my `FrameLayout` that achieves such an effect. If it's not possible at all, how do I get started with implementing it programmatically in my `MultiModeListener` callbacks.

PS: A look at [Color State documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) suggests we can only set `andoird:color` attribute in the `item` that we define in our `Selector`. I hope I am wrong.

**Edit - 1**

Attempted to use `layer-list` like so:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_activated="true">
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/ic_done_white_24dp" />
        </item>
        <item android:drawable="@color/holo_purple" />
    </layer-list>
  </item>
</selector>
```

Couldn't set `android:drawable` to a semi transparent color like `#80000000`. But that didn't work. And the `bitmap` is not visible anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this can be achieved using `LevelListDrawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/img1"
        android:maxLevel="1"
        />
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/img2"
        android:maxLevel="2"
        />
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/img3"
        android:maxLevel="3"
        />    
</level-list>
```

Once you set the drawable to an `ImageView`, you can call `imageView.setImageLevel(2)` to choose the respective image. You can have as many levels as you want.

Answer (score 0):

to create a drawable with an image and a background color you should use the following setup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item>
         <color android:color="@color/YourColor" />
     </item>

     <item>
         <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/YourImage" />
     </item>

</layer-list>
```